# Why does transposing a numpy array rotate it 90 degrees?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, caffe

I am trying to read images from an `lmdb` `dataset`, augment each one and then save them into another `dataset` for being used in my trainings.
These images axis were initially changed to `(3,32,32)` when they were being saved into the `lmdb dataset`, So in order to augment them I had to transpose them back into  their actual shape.
The problem is whenever I try to display them using either `matplotlib`'s `show()` method or `scipy`'s `toimage()`, they show a rotated version of the image. 
So we have :

```
img_set = np.transpose(data_train,(0,3,2,1))
#trying to display an image using pyplot, makes it look like this:  
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img_set[0])
```

[image]

showing the same image using `toimage` :

[image]

Now if I dont transpose `data_train`, `pyplot`'s `show()` generates an error while
`toimage()` displays  the image well:
[image]

What is happening here?
When I feed the transposed data_train to my augmenter, I also get the result rotated just like previous examples.
Now I'm not sure whether this is a displaying issue, or the actual images are indeed rotated!
What should I do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, look closely. The transoposed array is not rotated but mirrored on the diagonal (i.e. X and Y axes are swapped).

The original shape is `(3,32,32)`, which I interpret as `(RGB, X, Y)`. However, `imshow` expects an array of shape `MxNx3` - the color information must be in the last dimension.

By transposing the array you invert the order of dimensions: `(RGB, X, Y)` becomes `(Y, X, RGB)`. This is fine for matplotlib because the color information is now in the last dimension but X and Y are swapped, too. If you want to preserve the order of X, Y you can tell `transpose to do so`:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((3, 32, 64))  # non-square image for illustration

print(img.shape)  # (3, 32, 64)
print(np.transpose(img).shape)  # (64, 32, 3)
print(np.transpose(img, [1, 2, 0]).shape)  # (32, 64, 3)
```

---

When using `imshow` to display an image be aware of the following pitfalls:

1. It treats the image as a matrix, so the dimensions of the array are interpreted as (ROW, COLUMN, RGB), which is equivalent to (VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, COLOR) or (Y, X, RGB).
2. It changes direction of the y axis so the upper left corner is img[0, 0]. This is different from matplotlib's normal coordinate system where (0, 0) is the bottom left.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.zeros((32, 64, 3))
img[1, 1] = [1, 1, 1]  # marking the upper right corner white

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

Note that the smaller first dimension corresponds to the vertical direction of the image.

Comment: Thanks alot, very well explained ;)